# Compiler version, name, and OS detection in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I need to detect the OS name, compiler name, and version of the compiler with C++, as I need to change the setup for each case.

How can I do that?

Comment: runtime or compile-time? gcc or cl (VS)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For most compilers you can find a list of predefined macros.

- VS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- gcc http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

Answer (score 3):

I recommend define platform in build scripts by providing **-D_i386 -DENDIAN=1234 -D_linux**. But if you still think another **predef** project is your friend:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to detect the operating system at compile-time. You will, however, be able to determine the compiler- virtually all compilers define macros indicating their presence, like `__GNUC__` or something like that for GCC and MSVC has `__MSC_VER__` or something similar. You'll have to check their documentation for the actual macro names, I've forgotten.

Edit: For clarification, you can check what system's headers are included. For example, the Windows headers define a number of macros like `WINNT_VER` which give the minimum version of Windows to be targetted. But you can't detect the compiler's executing OS.

Comment: Using `#ifdef`, I did conditional compilation based on `OS`. So, doesn't it mean that compiler found the underlying `OS`. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Mahesh: That's *target* OS, not compiler host OS.

Comment: So, it's end system `OS` on which the application is going to be installed. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you leave that task to the build environment.  Either using commands like `uname` if you can assume a posixy set up, or by any other mean which is deemed suitable.