# Importing std::tr1 into std - is it legal? Does it improve portability?

Tags: c++, compatibility, tr1

I have C++03 code that looks like this:

```
#include <boost/tr1/unordered_map.hpp>
...
std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, int> mystuff;
...
```

I started to wonder that i would suffer later if/when i convert my code to C++11, which (i guess) doesn't have `std::tr1::unordered_map` but has `std::unordered_map` instead. So i came up with the following hack:

```
namespace std
{
    using namespace ::std::tr1;
}
...
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> mystuff; // no tr1 now!
...
```

Is it legal (maybe importing stuff into `std` is forbidden)? Will it make it easier to port/interoperate with C++11 code?

Comment: My compiler (VS2010) still understands `std::tr1` even though everything now also exists in `std`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should not touch the `std` namespace: even if it works now, it can cause severe headaches later (with a new version of the compiler, on a different compiler, etc).

Update: Quote from the standard (C++ 2003, Section 17.4.3.1 "Reserved names") (found [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/MSC34-CPP.+Do+not+modify+the+standard+namespace)):

> It is **undefined** for a C++ program to **add declarations or definitions to namespace std** or namespaces within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add template specializations for any standard library template to namespace std. Such a specialization (complete or partial) of a standard library template results in undefined behavior unless the declaration depends on a user-defined type of external linkage and unless the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template. [emphasis mine]

Comment: I think the only interesting answers are those backed by some facts - like "what the standard says about that".

Comment: @akappa: unless those are trivia ;) Now, of course, what is and is not trivia is quite subjective. For example, I consider this to be trivial, while you apparently do not!

Comment: @MatthieuM.: this site is full of trivial questions, i.e., questions whose answer is trivial. So, either we decide to not answer to those question, or we concur that "triviality" does not mean anything in this site, only correctness and being factual does.

Comment: @akappa: I would propose a middleway: if you think it is trivial and does not warrant a quote, do so, others will judge and you'll be able to adapt :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. - this is exactly what happened in this case

Comment: A shame that the standard forbids it, considering if you limit it to importing only (not defining) there's [some nice stuff you can do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747005/backporting-nullptr-to-c-pre-c0x-programs). Oh well, I at least don't let `-pedantic` get in the way of forwards-compatibility.

Answer (score 7):

Importing stuff into `::std` is forbidden by C++11 17.6.4.2.1:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 3):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095556/how-to-handle-evolving-c-std-namespace-e-g-stdtr1shared-ptr-vs-std) is very similar to what you are asking about.

In particular, I like the answer which says "use autoconf to detect symbols availability and then use conditional defines to alias the right namespace with a given name".

Answer (score 1):

This kind of portability should only be attempted if you have a proof that you cannot support a particular library in a clearer way, and ideally you should surround it with `#ifdef`s specific to that particular environment.

The point of `tr1` was to isolate your `std` from the stuff in `tr1`.