# C: How to conditionally compile certain parts of code based on Compiler Type?

Tags: c, conditional-compilation

I would like to conditionally compile certain parts of code based on Compiler Type is there any macro for that?

Like this:

```
#if defined (COMPILER_TYPE e.g. GCC)
// Compile this
#elif defined (COMPILER_TYPE e.g. Visual Studio C Compiler)
// Else this
#endif
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiler version, name, and OS detection in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724925/compiler-version-name-and-os-detection-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if these macros are defined, `__GNUC__` for GCC and `_MSC_VER` for MSVC.