# Printing the c++ compiler name

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have been working with qt creator and recently tried to change the compiler from gcc to clang. Since I don't get any info (or can't see it) on whether this worked (I'm struggling to understand the interface) I wanted to ask if there's a way for my c++ code to print out the compiler under which it's being compiled.

Comment: May be duplicated with:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724925/compiler-version-name-and-os-detection-in-c take a look on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilers set certain `#define`s to help out with things like this.

In your case,

```
#ifdef __GNUC__ //GCC
//do whatever GCC-specific stuff you need to do here
#endif

#ifdef __clang__ //clang
//do whatever clang-specific stuff you need to do here
#endif
```

[This page on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/) shows a list of such compiler-specific `#define` values.

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, clang sets `__GNUC__`, and possibly `__GNUC_MINOR__` and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__`. You might be better off using a double test to make sure clang isn't misleading you:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
//do whatever GCC-specific stuff you need to do here
#endif
```

Comment: Note that clang++ is "gcc compatible", and thus defined `__GNUC__`!

Comment: As noted in the linked page, many compilers define `__GNUC__` to say they are compatible with GCC. Maybe better to check for e.g. `__GNUC_MINOR__`.

Comment: you can use #elif which won't require `__GNUC_MINOR__`

Comment: Thanks, edited my answer. I don't use clang so I wasn't familiar with that pitfall.

Comment: @Jekyll I think that's slightly risky, though, because it relies on the clang test going first. If op later hand-writes another compiler check and forgets about the `__GCC__` pitfall, that could come back to bite them.

Comment: @computerfreaker `#elif defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)` also because `__GNUC_MINOR__` I suspect is defined for clang as well. you can run `clang -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null` to verify that.

Comment: @Jekyll I don't use clang so I can't verify whether it defines `__GNUC_MINOR__` or `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__`, but I'll edit my answer once more to reflect the possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [informational macros of boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.boost_informational_macros).

```
#include  <boost/config.hpp> 

#ifdef BOOST_CLANG

printf("Successfully changed to clang\n");

#endif
```